# Center an icon image which is inside image which is inside stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistackview

Hey guys i want to center an image inside an image which is inside stackview.

```
let stackview = UIStackView()
stackview.addArrangedSubview(imageview)
imageview.addSubview(anotherimageview)
```

I want anotherimageview centered which is an icon image.

Comment: Can you show the desired output and actual output as images?

Comment: hi there, did you try to do that in the storyboard?

Comment: Hi, I am doing it Programatically.

Comment: @Sweeper I want it to be like play icon image inside image thumbnail image.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `anotherImageView` as a subview of `imageView` setup its constraints in the way you want.

So, after this line:

```
imageview.addSubview(anotherimageview)
```

Add the following:

```
anotherimageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
anotherimageview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
anotherimageview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
// And do the same for the width and height constraints.
```